# Is there a way to automatically fetch the performance dashboard reports to gitlab in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, dashboard

I would like to fetch the sql server performance dashboard reports to my gitlab location, and just curious to know is there a way to automate the task.

For example, once a week I need to fetch the reports to Gitlab.

Please share your valuable inputs.

Best Regards,
Maddy

I can manually pull the reports and save it to either word or pdf format.
And I am not able to find a way to automate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure that generates the performance dashboard report.
Than you should create a SQL Server Agent job that executes the stored procedure.
Than you shoudl create a PowerShell script that uses GitLab REST API to upload the report to GitLab.
And add a step in the SQL Server Agent job that executes the PowerShell script to upload the report to GitLab. Like that:

```
$GitLabUrl = "https://gitlab.com"
$ProjectId = "123456"
$BranchName = "master"
$FilePath = "C:\Reports\PerformanceDashboardReport.pdf"
$AccessToken = "your_access_token"

$headers = @{
    "PRIVATE-TOKEN" = $AccessToken
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$GitLabUrl/api/v4/projects/$ProjectId/repository/files/$FilePath" `
    -Headers $headers `
    -ContentType "multipart/form-data" `
    -Body @{
        "branch" = $BranchName
        "commit_message" = "Upload Performance Dashboard Report"
        "content" = Get-Content -Path $FilePath -Raw
    }
```

Comment: Hi Dmitrii, thanks for your valuable advice. I am working on it